# Determine the time complexity

Tags: java, big-o

Can someone help determine the time complexity of this code. Is this just O(1)? If it is not can someone help explain it? I'm not 100% sure about my answer so I need a second opinion to see if this function is O(1).

```
    public static void secMax(int[] arr)
    {
        int n = arr.length - 1;
       

        if (some condition not relate to n)
        {
           
            if(arr[a] * arr[b] > temp)
            {
                //print
            }
            else
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(arr[y] * arr[x] > second)
            {
                //something
            }
            else
            {
                //something else
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: `O(1)` - no loops or other hard calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is O(1). You don't have any loop that traverses through the array. And you don't have any recursive call. Your method only have few if/else conditions. If you check carefully, your method only do fixed number of operations & that doesn't vary depending on the input array length. So time complexity is constant.

Answer (score 2):

It is O(1). The program just simply flows from top to bottom through a few conditional statements. No block of code executes more than once, so it has constant complexity.

Answer (score 1):

It's O(1) in time complexity, since you don't do any loops to traverse your argument array, neither recursive calls

Comment: How is this any different from the earlier answer by aatwork?

Comment: We said the same, I just find my answer shorter and more direct.
The question explicitly asked for an explanation if the time complexity wasn't O(1), so i only confirmed that it was and briefly said why.
In this cases should i delete my answer?

Comment: No need, you can leave your answer here since it has been upvoted. But in the future, when posting a second (or third, etc.) answer to a question, if you can write it so that it adds more detail to previous answers, clarifies an aspect that was confusing or outright incorrect, or gives a different perspective on the problem, that's the kind of answer that Stack Overflow users tend to find most valuable; check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) out. Still, thank you for volunteering your time and welcome to SO!

Comment: If you want to highlight an important part of an answer, this is usually better done as a comment (yes, it is frustrating to be unable to post comments before you have some reputation, I know) or an edit suggestion (as long as it is not too intrusive). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment for details.